# Xaml animation for button style to change background color

Tags: xaml

I have a xaml style to change background on hover for button, but i want to do it with animation.
I need some help this is my code.

```
<Style x:Key="MyButtonStyle2" TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True"/>
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                        <Border Name="border" 
                            BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                            Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" 
                            BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" 
                            Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                            <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                        </Border>

                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                <!-- <Setter TargetName="border" Property="Background" Value="#FF292929" /> -->
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
```

I tried some code i see on net but it didnt work and i got exceptions like background is brush and you cant use color animation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using [VisualStateManager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-app-sdk/api/winrt/microsoft.ui.xaml.visualstatemanager?view=windows-app-sdk-1.3)? You can add a VisualStateManager as the first child of the ControlTemplate, and then add a Storyboard w/a DoubleAnimation (or another type of animation, if desired) to animate the background.
Alternatively, you can just use a Setter in the VisualState to change the background instantaneously without an animation, just depends on what you're going for!